# Google Spreadsheet Columns Not Containing

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-docs

I'm trying to filter out data sets in Google Spreadsheets to get something along the lines of:

`=not(search("#"; (sort(unique(A:A)))))`

Basically, I want all of `A:A`, except columns containing the string `#`

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: This still isn't working, but it seems to be a bit closer to what I'm wanting: `=sort(unique(filter(A:A, not(search("#"; A:A)))))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,ISERROR(SEARCH("#",A:A)))))`